# Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only - Empty or incorrect report data

Tags: php, http, http-headers, content-security-policy

I have problems with CSP report data (Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only).

1. In report I only get the root domain https://******.com. But I'm expecting the full path.
2. **Referrer** is always empty, but I need to get this data.

For example: `<iframe src="https://*******.com/en/login" width="800" height="800" title="Test Frame"></iframe>`.

Could someone help me with this?

Header: 'Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: frame-ancestors 'self'; report-uri https://******.com/api/security-report'

```
{
  "csp-report": {
    "document-uri": "https://******.com/",
    "referrer": "",
    "violated-directive": "frame-ancestors",
    "effective-directive": "frame-ancestors",
    "original-policy": "frame-ancestors 'self'; report-uri https://******.com/api/security-report",
    "disposition": "report",
    "blocked-uri": "https://******.com/",
    "status-code": 200,
    "script-sample": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you put your CSP header to iframe or the page itself, or both?

Comment: Does this happen with all major browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [this](https://www.tollmanz.com/content-security-policy-report-samples/)  article :

> The spec further states that if the violating URI is from the same origin as the document-uri, the URI fragment can remain. If not, only the URI origin should be reported. Only Firefox did this incorrectly. For Firefox 5.0 - 41.0, it always reported the full URI, including the fragment, for every blocked-uri value. All other browsers that reported a blocked-uri (some older browsers didn’t) correctly reported the URI with and without the fragment in the correct cases.

blocked-uri that you get can be varied based on the origin the violation occurred, browser u are using - your csp version and etc. u can change any of them to test again your requirements.

and about the referrer, u did not have any referrers trigger CSP reports because none the violating resources were caused by a referrer.

- [the article](https://www.tollmanz.com/content-security-policy-report-samples/)  will illustrate this too with clear explanation.